# How can two section be connected if the latter have h1 in starting line?

Tags: html, css

```html
<section class="first">
</section>
<section class="second">
    <h1>something is here</h1>
</section>
```

If I were to give a background color to both sections, they appeared separately. How can make the separation go?

Comment: Browsers usually have some CSS added to make the text look readable even if it does not have a CSS or the CSS has not loaded yet. You can use a good [CSS reset](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) to override the predefined browser styling.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers can have default settings for margins on some element types.

In this case you are seeing a default margin on the h1.

This snippet explicitly removes this, but sometimes you will see style sheets starting with

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

to ensure the defaults are removed for everything and then add the required settings in explicitly.

```css
.first {
  background: pink;
  height: 100px;
}

.second {
  background: cyan;
}

.second h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="first">
</section>
<section class="second">
  <h1>something is here</h1>
</section>
```

Note: you can find out what is setting margins etc by using your browser's dev tools inspect facility, look at a specific element and you will see all the styles that have been applied and where they came from.

Comment: Thanks, it solved my query. ☺

Answer (score 0):

Give them both the same background and make sure they have `margin: 0`